# env_variables in app.yaml is unavailable while it builds docker container

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, elixir

I have 2 yaml files for Google App Engine.
I'd like to change environment variables by yaml file, so I'm using `env_variables` in the yaml files.

I also have a Dockerfile for building elixir container. The Dockerfile uses environment variables during the build.

```yaml
env_variables:
  REDISHOST: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'
  REDISPORT: 'XXXX'
  CLOUD_SQL_HOST: "XXXX:host"
```

Although I defined environment variables like that, Dockerfile cannot load the `env_variables`.

```
IO.inspect(System.get_env("CLOUD_SQL_HOST"), label: :host)
```

I wrote `IO.inspect()` to print `CLOUD_SQL_HOST`. In my local environment, it prints a content of the variable properly.

```
> MIX_ENV=prod mix compile
host: "XXXX:host"
```

But it does not print a content when I run `gcloud app deploy`.

```
Step 12/28 : RUN mix do deps.get, compile
 ---> Running in 7a1321b23cdb
host: nil
** (ArgumentError) argument error while evaluating config/prod.exs between lines 25 and 29
```

Is there are hints of the problem?
I read [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docker/issues/91) and tried some ways, but the problem is not solved yet...

Comment: How exactly are you reading the System envs in Elixir?  Is your config using the `runtime.exs` file?  Would something like https://hex.pm/packages/dotenvy help?

Comment: It does not use `runtime.exs`. I'll check it out.